# google maps in java script not working on second click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using this code to display map on my website

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address ="";

  function map(){
   alert("insisde");
  if(!document.getElementById('val').value){
  alert('Enter Val 1 Value');
  }
  else if (!document.getElementById('val2').value){
  alert('Enter Val 2 Value');
  }
  else if (!document.getElementById('val3').value){
  alert('Enter Val 3 Value');
  }
  else{
    address += document.getElementById('val').value;
    address += document.getElementById('val2').value;
    address += document.getElementById('val3').value;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(13);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 

                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >

 <input id="val" />
 <input id="val2" />
 <input id="val3" />
 <button onClick="map()" >Add Map</button>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:50%; height:50%;">
</body>
</html>
```

it is working fine when user click on it and add address the first time but when the user changes its address and clicks add map button or just presses the add map button the second time it is giving an error on log

`asd.html:78 Uncaught TypeError: map is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to initialize the map every time you call geocoder. Just initialize it on document load and then only display the marker with geocoder results. Every time you call geocode you will just remove the old marker from map. Try this:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = null;
  var marker = null;

  $(document).ready(function(){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
      navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  });

  function geocode(){
      if(marker) marker.setMap(null);
      var geocoder;
      var address ="";
  if(!document.getElementById('val').value){
  alert('Enter Val 1 Value');
  }
  else if (!document.getElementById('val2').value){
  alert('Enter Val 2 Value');
  }
  else if (!document.getElementById('val3').value){
  alert('Enter Val 3 Value');
  }
  else{
    address += document.getElementById('val').value + " ";
    address += document.getElementById('val2').value + " ";
    address += document.getElementById('val3').value;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(13);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 

                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >

 <input id="val" />
 <input id="val2" />
 <input id="val3" />
 <button onClick="geocode()" >Geocode</button>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:50%; height:50%;">
</body>
</html>
```